# How to dispatch state of texinput onchangetext to reducer using mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I want the states of my textinput to be dispatched to the reducer and change the state of of that reducer by the new state. I also want to be able to view these changed states in a new screen (globally) using mapStateToProps. I am roughly new to redux and I have tried everything possible, but I can seem to get it to work.

Is there any way to do that? I researched and found examples but not the way I want to do it.

I clarify my code is just an example so that you understand what I want to do, do not take it as a guide as I do not know if it works that way

Below are the important part of my code:

Process.Js

```
      import { connect } from 'react-redux';

      import {
        receiverNameChange,
        receiverPhoneChange,
        totalParcelsChange } from './actions';



      class Process extends Component {
        static navigationOptions = {
          header: null,
        }

        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            totalParcels: 1,
            receiverPhone: '',
            receiverName: '',
          };
        }



        onChangeTotalParcels(number) {
          const totalParcels = parseInt(number);
          if (number.length === 0) {
            this.setState({ totalParcels: '' });
          } else {
           this.setState({ totalParcels });
          }
          this.props.totalParcelsChange(number);
        }

        onChangeReceiverNumber = (receiverPhone) => {
          this.setState({
            receiverPhone
          });
          this.props.receiverPhoneChange(receiverPhone);
        }

        onChangeReceiverName = (receiverName) => {
           this.setState({
             receiverName
           });
           this.props.receiverNameChange(receiverName);
        }

        render() {
          return (
              <View style={styles.AndroidSafeArea}>
                    <InputField
                      placeholder={"Enter receiver's name"}
                      onChangeText={this.onChangeReceiverName}
                      value={this.state.receiverName}
                    />

                    <InputField
                      keyboardType={'phone-pad'}
                      onChangeText={this.onChangeReceiverNumber}
                      value={this.state.receiverPhone.toString()}
                    />
                    <InputField
                      keyboardType={'phone-pad'}
                      onChangeText={this.onChangeTotalParcels}
                      value={this.state.totalParcels.toString()}
                    />

              </View>
          );
        }
      }


       const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
       totalParcelsChange: number => {
       dispatch(totalParcelsChange(number));
       },
       receiverNameChange: receiverName => {
       dispatch(receiverNameChange(receiverName));
       },
       receiverPhoneChange: receiverPhone => {
       dispatch(receiverPhoneChange(receiverPhone));
       },
      });

      export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Process);
```

Receive.js

```
      import { connect } from 'react-redux';

      import {
        receiverNameChange,
        receiverPhoneChange,
        totalParcelsChange } from './actions';



      class Receive extends Component {
        static navigationOptions = {
          header: null,
        }

        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {

          };
        }


        render() {
          return (
              <View style={styles.AndroidSafeArea}>
              <Text>{this.props.receiverNameChange}</Text>
              <Text>{this.props.receiverPhoneChange}</Text>
              <Text>{this.props.totalParcelsChange}</Text>
              </View>
          );
        }
      }


      export default connect(null, null)(Receive);
```

Reduce.js

```
      import { GET_TOTAL_PARCELS, GET_RECEIVER_NAME, GET_RECEIVER_PHONE } from './actions/types';

      const initialState = {
        receiverName: '',
        receiverPhone: '',
        number: 0,
      };

      const ProcessReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
          case GET_TOTAL_PARCELS:
            return {
              ...state,
              number: action.payload
            };
          case GET_RECEIVER_PHONE:
            return {
              ...state,
              receiverPhone: action.payload
            };
          case GET_RECEIVER_NAME:
            return {
              ...state,
              receiverName: action.payload
            };

          default:
            return state;

        }
      };

      export default ProcessReducer;
```

Actions

```
      import { GET_RECEIVER_NAME, GET_RECEIVER_PHONE, GET_TOTAL_PARCELS } from './types';

      export const receiverNameChange = (receiverName) => {
        return {
          type: GET_RECEIVER_NAME,
          payload: receiverName
        };
      };

      export const receiverPhoneChange = (receiverPhone) => {
        return {
          type: GET_RECEIVER_PHONE,
          payload: receiverPhone
        };
      };

        export const totalParcelsChange = (number) => {
          return {
            type: GET_TOTAL_PARCELS,
            payload: number
          };
        };
```

Kindly correct me where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I in order for your component in **Receive.js** to access the state from redux, you should have a **mapStateToProps**, use it like so:

```js
class Receive extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
      return (
          <View style={styles.AndroidSafeArea}>
            <Text>{this.props.receiverName}</Text>
            <Text>{this.props.receiverPhone}</Text>
            <Text>{this.props.number}</Text>
          </View>
      );
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    receiverName: state.receiverName,
    receiverPhone: state.receiverPhone,
    number: state.number
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Receive);
```

To have a single source of truth in your **Process.Js**, you should remove the local state in your **Process** component and replace the values same as we did in **Receive** component and you can remove setState.

Hope this helps your problem.